# Не вижу возвращённый массив

Tags: ооп, массивы, java

Возможно, я как новичок в Java чего-то просто упустил/не понял. Вот суть проблемы:
Мне нужно получить в одном из методов массив, возвращаемый другим методом. 
Вот то, что массив создаёт:

```
public String[] getDriversArray() throws Exception {
        Connection dbh = Db.getConnection();
        Statement st = dbh.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from workers");        
        String[] drivers={};
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            drivers[i]=rs.getString("name");
            i++;
        }
        return drivers;
}
```

Вот фрагмент метода, который должен получать и обрабатывать данные:

```
int i=0;
String Html = "";
String[] drivers=getDriversArray();            
for(String dName : drivers){
   if(i>0) Html+=", ";
   Html+=dName;
   i++;
}
```

Он, однако, этих данных или не видит, или не обрабатывает. Если я возвращаю не массив, а строку - он всё прекрасно видит. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Что значит «не видит»? Так не бывает. Вы уверены, что количество элементов в массиве не 0?

Comment: Могу и правда поспорить, что ваш массив пустой, и что выполнение **не** заходит внутрь `while(rs.next())`. Потому что в нём вы индексируете массив за его пределами, так что вы бы получили `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Это значит, что `ResultSet` пустой.

Comment: Данные извлекаются из БД. Я писал, что, если запихиваю их не в массив, а в строку, то получаю их без проблем.

Comment: Этого не может быть в принципе. Если `rs` содержит записи, ваш код вылетит на первом же `drivers[i]=rs.getString("name");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть пустой массив `String[] drivers={};`
То как вы можете обратится к элементу массива `drivers[0]`, и так далее? Их же не существует.
Скорее всего `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from workers");` получает 0 записей. Попробуйте в отладчике - поставьте `breakpoint` на этой строчке и пошагово пройдите код

Comment: Подождите-ка. Он пустой сразу после инициализации. Дальше он ведь заполняется данными, полученными из БД. Вот эта строка внутри while -
drivers[i]=rs.getString("name");
И данные, действительно, успешно извлекаются - выше я написал, что собираю эти данные не в массив, а в строку, то без проблем получаю возвращаемое значение.
Или я таки какого-то нюанса не понял?

Comment: В Java массивы не динамические, как в JavaScript или PHP. Размер массива задаётся при его создании и не может быть изменён. Строкой `String[] drivers={};` вы создали массив нулевой длины. Массивы ненулевой длины создаются так: `Stringp[] drivers = new String[N]`, где `N` - длина массива. В вашем случае заранее определить длину массива проблематично, поэтому лучше воспользоваться коллекциями (например, List).

Comment: @fori1ton а можете пример написать или дать ссылку на использование подобного решения?

Comment: @srgg67: 5 минут чтения документации заменяют полчаса поиска в гугле и день ожидания ответа на форуме. Создавайте пустой список при помощи [`new ArrayList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29), добавляйте новый элемент в конец, увеличивая длину списка, при помощи [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29).

Comment: Отлично, пошёл читать :) 
Но перед уходом позвольте концептуальный вопрос - а если мне нужно извлечь многомерный "массив" - в случае, если выбираю из таблицы значения более, чем одного столбца? Чтобы потом в двойном цикле построить таблицу сотрудников, например? Каков подход в Java в данном случае?

Comment: Создать класс "Сотрудник" и вставлять в список объекты этого класса. В классе сотрудник будут поля "имя", "должность", "зарплата" и т. д. в зависимлости от того, какую информацию вы храните в базе. И ещё, не создавайте список как `new ArrayList()`. Такой список не типизирован и может включать в себя объекты любых классов, что потенциально ведёт к `ClassCastException`. Канонiчное объявление списка - с помощью дженериков: `new ArrayList<String>()`. Так он будет принимать только строки.

Comment: А в будущем, возможно, перейти на ORM фреймворк, например Hibernate. Но знания JDBC все равно будут полезны